# Is Java suitable for working with other external processes/applications?

Tags: java, memory, process, editor

I would like to write something similar to [Football Manager Real Time Editor](http://www.fmrte.com/) in Java, allowing the application to make changes to values inside the Football Manager game. Is this possible in Java?

I understand Java works with in a virtual machine, but does that stop it interacting with other applications in memory. If not what part of the API should I be looking at?

If it isn't possible, what language should I look to develop a language like this in, I develop on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Java has reasonable facilities for spawning external processes (look up the `ProcessBuilder` class). You can read and write to a process' streams fairly easily and check the return value. Sharing the memory locations of this process can be done with `JNI`, but it is far from trivial.

Comment: I've had a quick look at ProcessBuilder (on my phone at the moment) and it doesn't look like it would be able to edit the existing football manager game process?

Comment: Correct, ProcessBuilder is for starting processes